# Unable to clone git repository from bitbucket in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

I'm new to ubuntu, git and bitbucket.

So, here is my problem:

When I clone from bitbucket as https it gives me this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://user@bitbucket.org/project/my_project.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable

And if I clone from bitbucket as ssh it gives me this error:

> Cloning into 'my_project'...
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I have installed Git on my Ubuntu 14.04
Did I miss something? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even i faced the same problem when i was cloning from a repo to my local using git. Make sure you have generated public keys and private keys properly : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ and also place the id_rsa(private key) under .ssh folder in your home directory

Comment: for bitbucket : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: Thank you! my friend @ranjansaga , it is worked. Thanks a lot.